# Cloud Firestore query/filter with bitwise operators

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to query all documents on my Cloud Firestore database which have an identifier that returns `true` when performing certain bitwise operations on it. I have looked into [structured query operators](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1beta1/StructuredQuery#Operator_1) but bitwise operators do not seem to be supported.

The filtering should be performed on the server side.

Am I missing out on something? Is there any way I can use bitwise operators for my queries? If not are there any alternative solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firestore requires you to query against the *actual* values of fields stored in documents, as only those values are present in the indexes that Firestore creates.  It would not be scalable to scan an entire collection, performing any sort of transformation (bitwise or otherwise) to come up with matching documents.  In fact, Firestore does not allow any queries that can't be serviced by an efficient index lookup of document fields.

You could try to precompute the expected transformations and store the results of those for querying.  But if you want very flexible querying based on values that are not known ahead of time, Firestore isn't the right tool for the job.